# Particle.js not working in react production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-deployment, github-pages, particles.js

I am using Particles.js in my website, using React, I have the particles.js-master folder locally in the folder, and when i run the project on the development server (npm start) it works well, all the backgrounds show, but when i deploy the production build to GitHub pages, it stops working for some reason, you cant see the background.

I am even using typing.js and its working perfectly fine, I don't know why this is happening.

This Is The Repo -

https://github.com/Krish-Nerkar/Personal-Website

The master branch contains the non production code which works like a charm but the gh-pages branch which is deployed and is the production build does not work properly

Comment: I'm afraid that with this amount of information, it's going to be very difficult to provide any help. Is this code public? Could you please share the relevant pieces of code? Are you using particles.js directly or you are using the react-particles-js package?

Comment: Oh you are right, i'm sorry, i edited the post and included the repo link. And no i'm not using the package as i couldnt get it working with that, i'm using it directly